# CornerRadius and Shadow on a UIView using @IBInspectable Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, ibinspectable

Is it possible to have both `CornerRaduis` and a shadow on a `UIView`?

I set up a Custom class for a `UIView` which uses `@IBInspectable` to set a `cornerRadius` and a `addShadow` which can be `true` or `false`. When I set the `cornerRadius` the shadow doesn't display, if I take away the `cornerRadius` then it displays again. Thanks in advance!

Custom class:

```
import UIKit

class CustomUIView: UIView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0
    }

    @IBInspectable var useDefaultRadius: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            self.layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = newValue

        }
        get {
            if (useDefaultRadius) {
                    // Set default radius
                    self.layer.cornerRadius = 23
                }

            return self.layer.cornerRadius
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var addShadow:Bool = true{

        didSet(newValue) {
            if(newValue == true){
                self.layer.masksToBounds = false
                self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
                self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 3)
                self.layer.shadowRadius = 3

                self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
                self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
                self.layer.rasterizationScale =  UIScreen.main.scale
                print("trying to use shadow")
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, kindly accept it. as it encourages me to help more people.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than creating custom clas and changing class of uiview everytime, i prefer extending it.
I'm achieving this by extending UIView as mentioned below:

```
extension UIView {

    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            let color = UIColor.init(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
            return color
        }
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
        set {

            layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var shadowOffset : CGSize{

        get{
            return layer.shadowOffset
        }set{

            layer.shadowOffset = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowColor : UIColor{
        get{
            return UIColor.init(cgColor: layer.shadowColor!)
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowColor = newValue.cgColor
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var shadowOpacity : Float {

        get{
            return layer.shadowOpacity
        }
        set {

            layer.shadowOpacity = newValue

        }
    }        
}
```

And set properties in storyboard as:

[image]

That's it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You sir are my savior

Comment: shadow color getter method will not return the correct color if the user change the iPhone from darkMode to lightMode (while the app running). OR let me say it will not call again so this answer need to be edit

Comment: There's a bug. `shadowRadius`'s setter should be setting to `newValue` instead of itself.

Answer (score 1):

Set `true` `masksToBounds` in `addShadow:Bool` or you don't need to set masksToBounds in addShadow:Bool didSet method

```
@IBInspectable var addShadow:Bool = true{

        didSet(newValue) {
            if(newValue == true){
                //self.layer.masksToBounds = false
                self.layer.masksToBounds = true
                self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
                self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 3)
                self.layer.shadowRadius = 3

                self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
                self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
                self.layer.rasterizationScale =  UIScreen.main.scale
                print("trying to use shadow")
            }
        }

    }
```

You can follow: https://medium.com/bytes-of-bits/swift-tips-adding-rounded-corners-and-shadows-to-a-uiview-691f67b83e4a

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/07/18/swift-interface-builder/

Comment: @MatthewMitchell: you have added masksToBounds  true for corner radios > 0 in awakeFromNib so remove this line then your code will also work

Comment: Still not working, as soon as a I set a cornerRadius the shadow disappears

Comment: @MatthewMitchell I have updated answer. Can you try this one

Comment: if i remove that, cornerRaduis stops working completely

Comment: @MatthewMitchell Ok then you need Set true masksToBounds in addShadow and follow the given link

Comment: The problem here seems to be that the shadow is supposed to display outside the layer bounds, but since you have to set `masksToBounds=true` the shadow will be invisible (since it's outside the mask). You could create a view that uses a `CAShapeLayer` (`override static var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAShapeLayer.self }`}, and then set a rounded corner path (both as path and as shadowPath.  You should then also override  backgoundColor to get/set the shapeLayer's fillColor.

Comment: @Lutz: have you follow my given links

Answer (score 0):

Here's the trick, you have to Set `true` to `masksToBounds` then Set `false` to `masksToBounds` before adding shadow code.
you can check this method to make things clear:

```
func addShadow(color: UIColor, bottomOrTop: Bool = false, radius: CGFloat = 2, height: CGFloat = 3) {
        // These below line makes the trick to draw shadow with corner radius
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: height, height:  bottomOrTop ? height : height * -1)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = radius
        self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    }
```